# When using asio+ssl, the async_write doesn't send the data

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio

Given:

```
asio::ssl::stream<asio::ip::tcp::socket&> &m_socket;
async_write(self->m_socket, asio::buffer(self->m_v),
    [self, handler](asio::error_code ec, std::size_t s)
{
    handler(ec);
});
```

Result:
the handler is invoked before the data is sent (socket.send() function is called).
Result 2:
the data is actually sent after a long while - in my reproducible case about 1 min.
So, the sequence of events is as follows:
1. `async_write` is called;
2. handler is called;
3. data is sent.

I believe that correct sequence must be:
1. `async_write` is called;
2. data is sent.
3. handler is called;

It doesn't happen always, but very reproducible. I searched all over Internet for similar cases - found nothing.

I need advice: what to do about that. Is it a bug in asio or is it some tricky bug in my program and where to look to fix it.

I can reproduce the case easily, can provide log files etc.

Comment: How can you tell the order is `1. 2. 3.` and not `1. 3. 2.`? Did you mean you measure "3. the data is received" instead of "3. the data is sent"?

Comment: 1. I put timestamps in my log messages. I print a log message right before the async_write and at the beginning of its handler. I determine that 1 is before 2 based on those timestamps. As for 3, I used the Microsoft Message Analyzer to capture network traffic. Message Analyzer capture also contains timestamps. I believe that those timestamps mark the moment when the message enters the networking system  from asio code. Therefore I am sure that the order is 1. 2. 3.  

2. When I wrote the "3. the data is sent" I meant that the data was sent.

Comment: If you see a timestamp later than 2. in MMA, that doesn't mean it got sent after 2. (depending on where in the protocol you see the timestamp). It may just mean MMA saw it later. Also, things like Nagle's algorithm could be at play.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a timestamp later than 2. in MMA, that doesn't mean it got sent after 2. (depending on where in the protocol you see the timestamp). It may just mean MMA saw it later. Also, things like Nagle's algorithm could be at play.

Try setting TCP NODELAY, e.g.

```
socket.open(tcp::v4());
socket.set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
socket.async_connect(endpoint, handler);
```

Comment: I believe that MMA sees the message when it enters Windows networking subsystem, that is when socket.send function is called. Could you please explain why I should believe otherwise?

Comment: Because the MMA doesn't run in the kernel and all processes are fairly scheduled. Which one gets the next time slice on which core is not predictable or fixed

Comment: In my setting it is negligible. If the scheduling is fair, every process gets a chance to run within milliseconds. In my case, delay is 50 secs or so. Milliseconds are negligible.

Comment: Ooh. 50s. I don't know why I read across that. I thought you were drawing conclusions on ms timings. Sorry for that. Did you look at Nagle/TCP NODELAY?

Comment: Yes, I did (look). I don't think it is relevant here.